# How do I find my TeX Live local installation?

Tags: software-installation

Running Linux Mint, I found instructions to update TeX Live by uninstalling the old and reinstalling the new.  However, it indicates that the installation by default is at `/usr/local/texlive/...`  I wouldn't have installed in any specially different location, since I'm not very advanced at using this stuff, but I don't find any TeX directories under `/usr/local`.  I tried `which latex` and it responds `/usr/bin/latex` so I navigate to `bin` but it just has an executable, no TeX Live specific stuff that I can see.  And yet `latex --version` indicates that it is a TeX Live installation.  So I'm not sure what I ought to delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `find` or `locate`:

```
sudo find / -name '*texlive*'
```

or

```
locate texlive
```

This should provide a number of locations.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably texlive was installed by the distribution's means, at the system standard place. That may vary, but you'll probably find it somewhere like `/usr/share/texlive` and similar.

If you want to uninstall, use the distribution's tools for it.

Why do you want another texlive? Presumably the distribution's folks did the hard work of integrating the miriard packages and made the whole mesh well with other, peripheral tools (e.g. LaTeX support for stuff like gnuplot, support in assorted text editors, a GUI or two, ...).

Comment: I tried installing a package and it complained about my version being 2019 rather than 2020, so here I am.  Trying to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: It sounds like your problem is with package installation not the version of latex. Is your machine up to date? Are you installing from the distro repos? The output from the installation command that failed and the package you wanted to install could help a lot to solving that issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re updating or installing a package it should probably be done with the package manager I believe mint uses apt. There’s probably a GUI for it too. It will probably have a more up to date version that installs when you run update, assuming that’s how you installed texlive to begin with.

The installation lives in multiple places. bin is where the runable scripts and binaries are, lib for libraries, etc for configurations and probably docs and a few others. Package managers exist to keep track of which of these files belongs where so that these problems don’t come up.

The local location is typical for software that was compiled and installed locally for this particular machine, normally via a source build, and “make install”. If you installed texlive form source it might have a “make uninstall” target that can uninstall it for you.

You really should be using the package manager to install software unless there’s a specific reason not to though. Additionally the package manager is the best way to remove software as well. You can figure out which package owns the latex binary, probably texlive or similar and remove it.